# Cant find /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart

Tags: config.txt, lxde, raspbian-lite, kiosk

I am trying to follow [this](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-kiosk/) guide to set up a pi 3+ as kiosk but I get stuck at step 10. It says that this directory doesn't exist.
It seems that there is no .config file.

Any help is much appreciated
I am running the latest raspian lite stretch

Answer (score 2):

In 2018-11-13-raspbian-stretch.img (and -full.img), LXDE isn't installed, so the prior trick of changing `.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` to avoid screen blanking no longer works.

What does work is to append the following to `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`

```
[SeatDefaults]
xserver-command=X -s 0 -dpms
```

Answer (score 1):

Raspbian Lite is an OS tailored for running server software. To improve stability and reduce memory usage, it doesn't include any graphical user interface, so there's no LXDE installed.

If you need GUI, the recommended way to get it is to use regular Raspbian, which comes with a desktop environment pre-installed.